# What happens if you use an Amiibo in Smash that hasn't been unlocked as a character?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, wii-u, super-smash-bros-4, amiibo

What happens if you use an Amiibo of a character that is locked by default in Super Smash Bros for Wii U and 3DS (like Duck Hunt) before unlocking the character on that copy of the game?

Does it unlock the character?  Are you able to battle the Amiibo but the character stays locked?

Is there any difference in how the Wii U and the 3DS versions handle this?

Comment: I cannot answer your question since I don't own any Ammibo and am not planning to buy one. However, just for fun, I really wonder *why* you want to know that ! :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Amiibo will not unlock that character. The Amiibo just becomes an AI controlled character, which can be placed on your team or play against you.

There is no difference between the different versions of the game.

Comment: So you're saying that you're able to battle the character as an Amiibo but the character stays locked?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The Amiibo you buy will work right away no matter if you own the character or not because it is only an AI and you cannot use it this works for both versions of the game, and for dlc characters the same thing goes they will work if you haven't purchased them yet but they are only bots.